# Phantomjs Failed to click from non-angular to angular page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, phantomjs

I have a login page which is created in django. When i click the submit button. This submit itself will fail when i use phantomjs.

The error was:

> Message:
>       Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
>     Stack:
>       Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
>           at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)

Version:

> phantomjs: 2.1.1, protractor: 4.0.11, selenium: selenium-server-standalone-2.53.1.jar

Here is what i already did: but non of them works:

1. I already adjust the timeout, but still having the error.
2. After I check the screenshots logs. It is showing that the click of login is working because it is redirected in `landing page`
3. `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` is set.
4. change `.click()` to mousemove Then click. but still failed.
5. change `.click()` to `execute script click`. but still failed.

Here is my code.

```
it('fill values', () => { <-------------PASSED
  var currentUrl = browser.baseUrl+'/login/';
  browser.get(currentUrl);
  var loginField = browser.findElement(by.name('login'));
  loginField.sendKeys(browser.params.login.user);
  var passwordField = browser.findElement(by.name('password'));
  passwordField.sendKeys(browser.params.login.password);
});

it('login click', () => {  
    var signInButton = browser.findElement(by.css('form input.primaryAction'));
    signInButton.click();        <-------------FAILED
});

it('redirect after login', () => { <-------------PASSED
  expect(element(by.name('query')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Other info:

After click of button. it will redirect to `/` using 302, then redirect once more into `/en/` using 302, so the final page become `http://localhost/en/`